# Extracting data from 60,000 Facebook ID's in less than 6 hours?

Tags: ms-access, vba, facebook-graph-api, msxml, xmlhttprequest

I have downloaded the Faceboojk profile ID's of all of our Facebook fans to an access databse and have written a function to pull the locale data from the Facebook graph api. Here is an example of the graph api:-

http://graph.facebook.com/665117534

My code loops through each record and pulls teh data from the API like this:-

```
    Function fbl(fb_user_id As String) As String
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object, i As Long, vFF As Long, oResp() As Byte
    Dim FB_URL As String
    Dim fb_user_data As String

    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    FB_URL = "http://graph.facebook.com/" & fb_user_id

    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", FB_URL, False
    oXMLHTTP.Send

    Do While oXMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    fb_user_data = oXMLHTTP.responsetext

    n0 = InStr(1, fb_user_data, "locale") '
    If n0 = 0 Then
        locale_code = "PAGE"
    Else
        n00 = InStr(n0, fb_user_data, "}") '
        locale_code = Mid(fb_user_data, n0 + 6, n00 - n0)
        locale_code = Replace(locale_code, """", "")
        locale_code = Replace(locale_code, ",", "")
        locale_code = Replace(locale_code, " ", "")
        locale_code = Mid(locale_code, 5, Len(locale_code) - 6)
    End If

    fbl = locale_code

    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing

End Function
```

This works fine but testing a 100 records took 35 seconds which suggests that the whole table will take 5.6 hours. Is theire a more efficent, speedier way of doing this?

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: What timing have you done on the existing code: do you know where the time is being taken?  NB. Since you're not using an asynchronous call you don't need the loop checking for ReadyState immediately after the 'Send'.  You should also be able to re-use the xmlhttp object - no need to create a new one each time.

Comment: You are assuming the entire 35 seconds was the time to process the 100 records but at least part of that 35 seconds will be start-up time.

Comment: Great tips Tim, that seems to have really speeded things up, thanks for the heads up

Comment: +1 @TimWilliams you should put this into an answer!

Comment: THAT is why I never accept any app on FB !

Answer (score 0):

My approach has been to use a multi threaded C# application with System.NET.Sockets and [turn off the Nagle Algorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay.aspx).

I haven't seen many high performance computing applications written in VBA

**Edit**

Since you're using the XMLHTTP object you should retag this question to reflect that.  You may get a better response from people who know that API.